# Animated view on mono touch iPhone project with c#

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad, xamarin.ios, uiviewanimation

```
public override void ViewDidLoad ()
        {
            base.ViewDidLoad ();

            // Perform any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
            List<UIImage> myImages = new List<UIImage>();
            myImages.Add(UIImage.FromFile(@"image/1.jpeg"));
            myImages.Add(UIImage.FromFile(@"image/2.jpeg"));
             var myAnimatedView = new UIImageView(this.hatchAgeSubView.Bounds);
            myAnimatedView.AnimationImages = myImages.ToArray();
            myAnimatedView.AnimationDuration = 3; // Seconds
            myAnimatedView.AnimationRepeatCount = 4; // 0 = Loops Forever
            myAnimatedView.StartAnimating();
            hatchAgeSubView.AddSubview(myAnimatedView);
        }
```

as you see above there is an animation  with two images for 12 seconds.
I want to start another another animation just after 12 seconds. (at the end of the animation above)

Are there any call back method or are there any idea to make this next animation playing automatically.??

Answer (score 3):

If you're using iOS 4 or better you can use the new Animate method and get notified upon completion of the first animation sequence:

```
var delay = 0.0f;
UIView.Animate(delay, () => {
    UIView.SetAnimationRepeatCount(4);
    //Regular animation code goes here.

}, () => {
    // This fires when the first animation block above is completed
    //Second animation sequence code goes here.
});
```

***UPDATE***: Please do not call animations from ViewDidLoad it will make the experience laggy and your users unhappy. Try calling it async from ViewDidAppear. For more information on View Events check out my blog post on the subject:

http://blog.devnos.com/uiviewcontroller-y-u-no-fire-view-events

Comment: Can I call a method just after the animation finishes, if yes, I would like to invoke the method below inside callback.: to pass the other view.

Comment: InvokeOnMainThread (delegate {  
    babyAge babyAgeViewController = new babyAge (this.coreLife);
    babyAgeViewController.ModalTransitionStyle = UIModalTransitionStyle.CrossDissolve;
    babyAgeViewController.BabyAgeClosed += HandleTTViewControllerClosed;
    this.PresentModalViewController (babyAgeViewController, true);
   });

Comment: Short answer, yes. Though this assumes that the reference to the delegate HandleTTViewControllerClosed is valid around after the current view controller has been pushed back in the stack, but it's likely not. I would restructure this pattern.